# How to get regex matched string in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a issue. I have a string that contains a pattern and if string contains that pattern then it should be stored inside an variable.

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/@([0-9]+)/i);
if(pattern.test('@2 ajshfd @32 asd')
// here i need to store the matched string inside a variable and replace it with another string.
```

for eg:- input:- @2 ajs @32 hfdasd output:- Hi ajs hello hfdasd

Need help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: updated based on question changes
You can try in 2 steps, first [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and then [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
let pattern = new RegExp(/@(\d+)/i)
let str = '@2 ajshfd @32 asd'

let arrOld = []
let arrNew = ['Hi', 'hello']

let m
do {
  m = pattern.exec(str)
  if (m) {
    arrOld.push(m[1])
    str = str.replace(pattern, arrNew.shift())
  }
} while (m)

console.log(arrOld)
console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string matches your pattern, you can split it with ***'] '***. This will create an array. You can pick up second value in that array and append ***'Hi '*** to it.

```js
var pattern = new RegExp(/@\[([0-9]+)\]/i);

var str = '@[2] ajshfdasd';
if(pattern.test(str)){ 
  var name = 'Hi ' + str.split(/\] /)[1];
  console.log(name)
}
```

Comment: pattern updated ... and not getting from this as well

Answer (score -1):

Not clear what you are trying to do. But have you read about String.prototype.replace() ? Maybe you can find your answers while studying it.

Comment: This is not an answer. You can put it as a comment. If you don't have privileges to add comment, check this out:: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: Nobody is going to write a code logic for you from scratch here. You have to try atleast.

Comment: And your try seems more like the todo's commented in the code

Comment: Dude, I am not the person who asked the original question. As you are new to the answering (looking at your reputation), I am just helping you to understand the best practices here. Have a look at the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.  All the best !!!

Comment: @ivp i overlooked as though who had commented. But go ahead and look up for what exactly stack overflow is for instead of providing direct solutions or you can just go here since you like links https://stackoverflow.com/tour scroll down and see " Don't ask about ..." read the first line.Where person who posted it haven't even tried for it.

Comment: Thats ok. However, statements without answers about learning, references etc can always be comment. They are not 'Answers'. Hope you understand it. Good bye!!